# What is the most stable kernel for my ALE-L21 (2015) alice and ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, kernel, performance, 7.1-nougat, aosp

I'm pretty sure that this is already a weak legacy device but I want it to be useful and stable in performance to the max. Can you suggest the ultimate kernel for my `7.1.2 AOSP` based custom ROM?

[image]

**Note**: I'm using a vanilla kernel.

Comment: custom kernels are always trial & error there is no most stable